# Puppteer cannot open shared object file libxshmfence.so.1

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

While executing the puppeteer script on ubuntu (VERSION="20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)") server I am getting this error because of some missing peer dependencies (I think).

Thanks already

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-XXXXXX/chrome-linux/chrome`
needs shared library `libxshmfence.so.1`.

Run the following command to install `libxshmfence.so.1`.

```sh
sudo apt install libxshmfence-dev
```